# Makefile: "multiple target patterns. stop."

Tags: java, makefile

**Of course I am being stupid again.**

Can anyone tell me why this;

```
$(shell compileJava.bat)
```

an expression without any variables, special characters, unwanted spaces, colons, etc. is causing error `Makefile:70: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.`.

I've searched the whole internet for an answer.

**What I am trying to do.**

I'm making a Java project involving natives. I have the structure like this;

```
+ root (project)
  -+ build
     -+ natives (for the built native libraries like dlls)
     -+ classes (for the built java classes)
     -+ generated (gradles compileJava task automatically generates jni header files)
  -+ src
    -+ main
      -+ java (all of the java source)
      -+ resources
      -+ c
        -+ Makefile (will be called to compile and link the c(++) code)
  -+ Makefile (the general makefile, error occurs in here at line 70)
  -+ compileJava.bat (calls gradlew compileJava with a jdk argument, but since im using 
      windows and make doesnt support colons, like C:, i had to put it in a batch file)
```

and the root Makefile is supposed to follow this procedure;

```
[1] call "compileJava.bat" to compile the java code & gen the headers (error occurs here)
[2] call "make -C src/main/c" to run the native build makefile
[3] call "jar cf <name> <contents>" to package all java code (and the natives) into a jar
```

***Links***

> My whole root Makefile: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pEVZ5N56)

> `compileJava.bat`: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sW84hh2r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `$(shell ...)` do?  It invokes a shell command, and it *evaluates to the standard output of the command*.

If you write a makefile like this:

```
$(shell true)
```

then the shell command prints nothing and so it expands to nothing, then make tries to evaluate nothing, and nothing happens.

If you write a makefile like this:

```
$(shell echo hi)
```

Then the shell comand prints "hi", and this function expands to the string "hi", so it's as if you wrote a makefile:

```
hi
```

and that, of course, is not a valid makefile.

So this:

```
$(shell make -C src/...)
```

expands *to the entire output of running make* which is obviously not a valid makefile at all.

You can avoid this by putting the results in a variable:

```
_tmp := $(shell make -C src/...)
```

But, I really think you need to rethink your whole approach.  Makefiles are not procedural programs like shell scripts.

Comment: ooooh thanks, but how would i call the batch file and the other make instance from make? or should i use a shell/batch script instead, like you said?

Comment: Yes, you should use a shell script or batch file.  You already ARE writing a shell script, you're just doing it in the most convoluted way possible by writing it in "makefile syntax".  Makefiles are good for situations where you have a lot of files that are built from other files, where you want to avoid updating things if the dependent files haven't changed.  They can also run disjoint operations in parallel for speed.  Makefiles are not good for writing a series of steps that you want to always run, and always run in the same order one after the other.  Use a script for that.

Comment: ah ok. ive translated my whole makefile to batch (because i use windows), but now the program just stops after the gradle task is done. do you know how to start a program in another console host using batch?

Comment: Sorry but I don't use Windows: I pretty much only use UNIX systems.  And, I especially don't like bat files: they're so obscure.  That question looks completely disjoint from the original question here so I recommend you create a new question and ask it, cutting and pasting the relevant parts of your batch file into the question (please don't use links to remote servers in StackOverflow: the goal is that other people can search SO for their issues) and formatting them properly, then use appropriate tags to draw the attention of Windows scripting folks.

Comment: okay thanks! also i used pastebin because i thought that the question would get really long and cluttered if i just posted the entire makefile and batch file in there (SO doesnt have make syntax  support i think

Comment: Indeed.  It's best to extract out the parts that are giving you trouble, into a minimal example that shows the problem and paste that.  Good luck!